# Pascal's set types analogue for Java

Tags: java, pascal

Pascal has a feature of set types. It allows nice constructs like this:

```
if i in [5..10] then
  ...
```

Are there any similar things in Java?

I came up only with this ugly construction that doesn't accept intervals:

```
if ((new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{5,6,7,8,9,10}))).contains(i))
  ...
```

Comment: `if i in [0..3, 7, 9, 12..15] then` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're right. You need an implementation of a `Set` in Java and have to populate it yourself with a loop if you want a non-sequential list of numbers.

Also, Java does not support the contruct of a *Range*. Other JVM laguages like Groovy and Scala however do.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491199/why-java-c-sharp-and-c-dont-have-ranges) may add some more colour

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are no such beautiful construct in Java. But [apache-commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) provides a [Range](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/math/Range.html) class which may suite your needs